# Hovering a div shows hidden div - jquery to prototype conversion

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have been trying for a few days using Prototype to show a hidden div when hovering over another div.
I have this working fine in jQuery but I could use some help porting it over to prototype.

When I hover over `.recent-question` I would like `.interact` to fade in or atleast appear.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".recent-question").hover(function(){
        $(this).find(".interact").fadeIn(2.0);
    }, function(){
        $(this).find(".interact").fadeOut(2.0);
    });    
});
```

```
<div class="recent-question"> 
    <img src="images/new/img-sample.gif" alt="" width="70" height="60" />
    <div class="question-text">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <p><a href="#">Yadda Yadda Yadda</p>
    </div>
    <div class="interact" style="display:none;">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Choice1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Choice2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Choice3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$$(".recent-question").each(function(div) {
   div.observe('mouseover', function(e) {
       div.down('.interact').appear(); //FadeIn
   });
   div.observe('mouseout', function(e) {
       var mouse_over_element;
       if (e.toElement) {
           mouse_over_element = e.toElement;
       } else if (e.relatedTarget) {
           mouse_over_element = e.relatedTarget;
       }

       if (mouse_over_element == null) {
           return;
       }
       if (!mouse_over_element.descendantOf(div) && div != mouse_over_element) {
           div.down('.interact').fade(); //FadeOut
       }
   });
});
```

Still have some bugs, sorry :(

**Detailed version:** http://jsfiddle.net/eRSu2/

**Based on:** http://mikeconley.ca/blog/2009/02/19/mouseover-mouseout-on-nested-elements/

Comment: Hi Rui,

Your response is the first I have received that actually caused some movement on the page. Thanks for that.

The problem is that the div.interact seems to show, blink and then disappear on hover and after the first hover it does not show the div.interact when hovering. Do you have any further suggestions?

Thanks for the help!!! It's really close!

Comment: Sorry phil, in my first example i was missing the event bubbling issue. I edited my original post and i think its working better now but still have one blink at fade's end :(

Comment: this wasn't exactly i needed. but it help me a lot. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use $$() and each() functions for traversing elements by classnames. use [script.aculo.us](http://script.aculo.us/) to make fadein/fadeout effects. Event.obseve() to handle events

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my answer is off topic but I would recommend you consider using jQuery instead of Prototype. Why? Simply because jQuery seems to have much more traction and wider acceptance then Prototype.

I used Prototype and Scriptaculous for a website of mine only to find out that it's quite hard to find plugins that are readily available for jQuery.

According to [The State of the Web](http://www.webdirections.org/sotw10/), 78% of professional web designers and developers survey use jQuery in comparison to 18% who use prototype.

Comment: I would love to use jquery but I cannot in this situation.